# c# strange user sync on list add

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I'm using 4 threads, all memory is unshared (all threads have it's own objects, and no sync, and no locks)
cpu usage 100%, then I uncomment:

```
private List<MyOrder> orders = new List<MyOrder>();
...
orders.Add(order);
...
```

"orders" isn't use anywhere else
now cpu usage about 80%, concurrency visualizer screens:

[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMGIH.png)

[Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYVTs.png)

on net framework 4.0/4.5

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to show more code. There is no synchronization in the code shown. (Except memory allocation. Can you try to set a big initial capacity on the list to ensure reallocation does not interfere with your measure)

Comment: What is implementation of `PositionManager.AddOrder`?

Answer (score 0):

i belive the problem is wrong syntax, a List work like this:
Example:

```
//For strings
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
//or for integers
List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Sorry for my inattention, List< MyOrder > orders, i've fixed the question